# View controller never deacllocated on assigning core-data relationship inside block

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-management, block

I am working on an app which makes use of Core Data. I am using parent/child contexts to access Core Data from both the main and background threads. The application makes use of Quickblox framework (don't bother if you aren't aware of this framework, you need not be aware of it to answer the question), I have to use the API of this framework which makes a call to a server, fetches data and hands the control back to me using a block. Control is always returned back on the main thread i.e the block always executes on the main thread.

Here's my code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
{
    QBResponsePage *page = [QBResponsePage responsePageWithLimit:ResponseLimit skip:0];
    [QBRequest messagesWithDialogID:weakSelf.dialog.id
                    extendedRequest:extendedRequest
                            forPage:page
                       successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *messages, QBResponsePage *page)
    {
       if(messages.count > 0)
       {
           NSArray *filteredArray=nil;

           NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Dialog"];
           NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@",weakSelf.dialog.id];
           [request setPredicate:predicate];
           NSArray *results=[weakAppDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

           Dialog *parentDialog=nil;
           if([results count]>0){
               parentDialog=[results objectAtIndex:0];
           }
           for(QBChatMessage *message in messages)
           {
               NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Chats"];
               NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"chat_Id == %@",message.ID];
               [request setPredicate:predicate];
               NSArray *results=[weakAppDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
               if([results count]==0){

                   if([message.dateSent compare:parentDialog.last_Message_Date]==NSOrderedDescending){
                       parentDialog.last_Message_Date=message.dateSent;
                       parentDialog.last_Message_User_Id=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:message.senderID];
                       parentDialog.lastMessage=message.text;
                   }
                   Chats *recievedChat=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Chats" inManagedObjectContext:weakAppDelegate.managedObjectContext];
                   recievedChat.sender_Id=[NSNumber  numberWithInteger:message.senderID];
                   recievedChat.date_sent=message.dateSent;
                   recievedChat.chat_Id=message.ID;
                   recievedChat.belongs=parentDialog;
                   recievedChat.message_Body=message.text;

               }
           }
           //commit main context
       }
       //update user profilepic
   } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
       //handle error
   }];

});
```

Everything works fine, but as soon as the statement `recievedChat.belongs=parentDialog;` gets executed, `dealloc` never gets called even after popping out the view controller containing code. Commented out this statement, obviously Core Data relationships won't work but dealloc gets called as expected.

I am confused. Please help guys.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dealloc` on what object does not get executed?

Comment: Hey jcaron, dealloc of the view controller which contains this code in its view will appear never gets called. :(

Comment: Note sure I see a reason at first sight. You should use **Instruments**, the allocations or leaks tools will help you to find the culprit. Core Data will keep references to the `Chats` objects, which will in turn keep a reference to `Dialog`, but I fail to see (from your provided code) what would keep a reference to the block or the view controller.

Comment: I used allocations and checked every time the view controller gets pushed a new instance of the view controller is getting allocated leaving the existing one in memory as it is. :( I could not find the statement which is causing it . Today i did trial and error method and comment and un commented all statements and found commenting recievedChat.belongs=parentDialog; deallocs view controller properly. Dont know whats the issue :(

Comment: You need to check the retains and releases. In the Allocations template, on the right side, check "Record reference counts". Start recording, then in Statistics / Allocation Summary, use the search box to find your view controller. Click once on the small circled arrow next to the name, then one the small circled arrow next to the Address. You'll see the full list of retains and releases. You can now try to find the culprit.

Comment: ok... lemme try that :)